# Regex: multiple lookbehinds

Tags: regex, terminal, grep, lookbehind

I'm struggling with this regex for days. I have this text:

```
alias -g NULL="> /dev/null 2>&1"    # redirect output
test                                # don't match
alias l="ls -lahGF"                 # list all
PROMPT=$'$FG[237]'                  # don't match
```

And I want to match `NULL` and `l` using `grep` or other terminal commands. Is it possible to directly match them without using groups?

I tried using `(?<=^alias )(?<=-g).+` with no result.

Comment: It's worth noting that the two look behinds you have used in sequence here will always fail since they conflict. The first asserts the the current character must be preceded by Start of string then literal `alias ` which is fine, but the second look behind then asserts that the same character must be preceded by literal `-g`. Look arounds are 'zero width' meaning they won't move the character position along when analyzing the source text. No character can be preceded by both `alias ` and `-g` at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the below grep command which uses a PCRE regex.

```
grep -oP '^alias(?:\s+-g)?\s+\K[^=]+(?==)' file
```

OR

```
grep -oP '^alias(?:\s+-g)?\s+\K\w+' file
```

OR

```
$ grep -oP '^alias(?:\s+-g)?\s+\K[^=]+' file
NULL
l
```

[`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final.
`\K` keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match.

Comment: Avinash could not use a positive lookbehind because (in all but a couple of languages) lookbehinds cannot be variable-length (here `\s+` being the problem). Thank heavens for `\K`!

Answer (score 3):

This may look a little rough, but it is very readable, as in *if it is an alias declaration, grab the alias literal*

```
grep ^alias test | grep -oP "\w+(?==)"
```

Comment: Is there a performance overhead by using two simpler `grep` commands instead of one complex one?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd guess @AvinashRaj answer is faster; that's not using  a more _complex_ regex, just a less common one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '$1=="alias"{p=$0; sub(/=.*$/, ""); split($0, a, " "); sub(/^.*# /, "", p); 
     print a[length(a)] ":", p}' file
NULL: redirect output
l: list all
```

Comment: Almost, except the `alias` was important. I'll update my question.

Comment: or my earlier `grep` can be changed to `grep -oP '^alias\h+.*?\K\w+(?==)' file`

Comment: A little update on this, can you please how to retrieve the description after the `#` and display it like `l: list all`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'sub(/^alias[^=]* /,"") && sub(/=.*/,"")' file
NULL
l
```